# syntax error case statement

Tags: sql

I am trying to write an sql statement but i am getting syntax error. I know it is do with my select and case statement but cant figure out.As the error is not descriptive. I am using redshift

```
select school_district_teacher_ind,customer_status,initial_pay_type,(select(
             CASE 
                  WHEN total_line_price = 0  
                     THEN 'free' 
                  ELSE 'paid'
             END
             ) 
      from storiacloud.schl_storia_revenue_fact_a)as a,count(distinct convert(varchar(100),[Otc_Order_Number])+'_'+ convert(varchar(100),[Otc_Order_Line_Number]))
from storiacloud.schl_storia_revenue_fact_a  as fact
inner join  
storiacloud.schl_storia_school_status as status
on fact.school_ucn = status.ucn
where date = '11/2/2015'
group by school_district_teacher_ind,customer_status,initial_pay_type,a
```

Below is the error

```
ERROR: Invalid Query: 
  Detail: 
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Invalid Query: 
  code:      8001
  context:   single-row subquery returns more than one row
  query:     5132289
  location:  25.cpp:69
  process:   padbmaster [pid=29183]
  -----------------------------------------------


Execution time: 0.16s
1 statement failed.
```

The results that i expect are [image]

Note first column customer type is school_district_teacher_ind in the above select statment

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Case expression, not case statement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your case was a subquery that is selecting from the same table as your main query. Try this;

```
SELECT  school_district_teacher_ind ,
        customer_status ,
        initial_pay_type ,
        CASE WHEN total_line_price = 0 THEN 'free'
             ELSE 'paid'
        END AS a ,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), [Otc_Order_Number]) + '_'
              + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), [Otc_Order_Line_Number]))
FROM    storiacloud.schl_storia_revenue_fact_a AS fact
        INNER JOIN storiacloud.schl_storia_school_status AS status ON fact.school_ucn = status.ucn
WHERE   date = '11/2/2015'
GROUP BY school_district_teacher_ind ,
        customer_status ,
        initial_pay_type ,
        CASE WHEN total_line_price = 0 THEN 'free'
             ELSE 'paid'
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want conditional aggregation.  The query is something like this:

```
select school_district_teacher_ind, customer_status, initial_pay_type,
       sum(case when total_line_price = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as free,
       sum(case when total_line_price = 0 then 0 else 1 end) as paid
from storiacloud.schl_storia_revenue_fact_a fact inner join  
     storiacloud.schl_storia_school_status status
     on fact.school_ucn = status.ucn
where date = '2015-11-02'
group by school_district_teacher_ind,customer_status, initial_pay_type;
```